# $\sqrt{9+x}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{5}{\sqrt{9+x}}$

Tags: polynomials

$$\sqrt{9+x}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{5}{\sqrt{9+x}}$$

In this problem, I keep getting stuck at once I have a square root left. I have tried using an algebra calculator but it doesn't tell me how it gets rid of the square root. Obviously I got rid of the denominator by multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{9+x}$ but I don't know how to proceed as the next step the calculator gets is always different from what I get.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The statement is false. Test it on $x=0.$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation + include the question in the body, not only in the title + your title must contain words, not only a formula (if any)

Comment: Is this question correct...OP pls check the denominator...is the square root only till $9$...I approved the edit without seeing the question :(

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad A more natural interpretation was possible but both lead to a wrong statement (see my 1st comment) + (again) title must contain words, not only a (LaTeX) formula

Comment: @AnneBauval I apologise for the wrong approval...actually I did it in haste...without seeing that the entire body

Comment: @AnneBauval: this seems to be an equation, not an identity

Comment: @Taladris Oh thanks! (Whence the necessity of words in the question!) Anyway, the OP should 1) check or correct the interpretation of the title 2) add words in it, like "How to solve the equation" 3) include the question in the body

Comment: I mean: in order to deserve *any* answer or hint.

Comment: Can you show you work? In particular, list out the equation that you get. We can continue from there by squaring the equation, but have to be careful for extraneous solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Assuming the problem has meant, $\sqrt{9+x}-\sqrt x=\dfrac5{\sqrt{9+x}}$

As $\sqrt{9+x}-\sqrt x=\dfrac9{\sqrt{9+x}+\sqrt x}$

we have $$\dfrac5{\sqrt{9+x}}=\dfrac9{\sqrt{9+x}+\sqrt x}$$

$$\iff5\sqrt x=4\sqrt{5+x}$$

Can you take it from here?